# "Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined" while trying to remove a div which has a tinymce instance

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

Here is the issue I am facing

1. I have a div which contains an instance of tinymce.
2. This instance of tinymce is within an unordered list within the same div
3. When I try to delete the main div on click of a button I am getting the
   "Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined" error.
4. But when I double click the button the div gets removed. But I want the div removed on
   the first click.
5. I have tried tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, tinymceId); ( tinymceID
   is the id of the tinymce textarea ) To remove the instance of tinymce but to no avail

Below is the code I am using to remove the div

```
$('div.form').on('click','a.cancel-btn',function(e){
    var kk = $(this);   
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.dialog').html('Are you sure you wish to delete this asset ? Selecting \'Yes\' will delete this asset.');    
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        buttons:{
            "Yes": function() {
                tinymceId = kk.closest('div.box2').find('textarea').attr('id');
                if (typeof(tinymceId) == 'string') {
                    if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById(tinymceId) != null)
                    {
                        tinymce.triggerSave();
                    tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', false, tinymceId);
                    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, tinymceId);
                        //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, tinymceId);
                        kk.closest('div.box2').find('textarea.tinymce_new').tinymce().remove();                   
                    }

                    kk.closest('div.box2').find('textarea').remove();
                    kk.closest('div.box2').find('textarea').remove();

                } 
                //tinyMCE.myClass.remove();
                 kk.closest('div.box2').remove();
                $(this).dialog("close");
                kk.click();
            },
            "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's to do with tinymce and not just a question of variable scope? Check by trying to remove the main div without having initialized tintmce.

Comment: Yes I am Sure as there are other divs in the same page which I do remove in the same way that does not show this error but only when I try deleting the div with tinymce this error shows up. If I remove the tinymce from the div it deletes without no issue

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is relevant to you because you haven't posted your tiny_mce initialisation code. I had the same problem when closing a fancybox with tiny_mce in it. You have the solution correct, ie you need to call this on close:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, tinymceId); //this is also needed apparently to avoid problems in IE
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, tinymceId);
```

However I tried this and it didn't work because I was initialising tiny_mce using the jquery method:

```
 $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
   //init code here
 });
```

If you initialised using this method then mceRemoveControl doesnt work, and I have no idea what the jquery alternative is.

My solution was to use the standard js init like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //init code here
});
```

you then call it after your page laods/fancybox opens with:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, tinymceId);
```

If you init tinyMCE like this then the removeControl works (at least it did for me). Hope this helps